# HTML4 Form using mattw@scriptarchive.com cgi script can I embed paypal button?

Tags: javascript, forms, paypal

Ok first I understand html4 and css and nothing else. I have created an html form to capture address etc and choose a book. The form action =  bookform.cgi is mattw@scriptarchive.com standard form with my web and email address. 
Question: can I embed a paypal button with a different form action address into my form and have data going to both form action addresses correctly? 
I have read a previous post which suggests using the following java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input[name='submit']").click(function() {
  $("#myForm").submit();
});
</script>
```

Please excuse my ignorance but exactly what does this do? Presumably "#myForm" would be replaced with "bookform.cgi" in my case, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    $("input[name='submit']").click(function() {
> ```

Select all inputs with a property "name" that has value "submit", and attach a click event handler.

> ```
>    $("#myForm").submit();
> ```

Select all elements with an id of "myForm" and invoke `submit()`;

What you need to do is define an `<input name='submit'>` and `<form id='myForm'>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to submit the same data to 2 locations:

```
<form id="formID" action="page1.cgi"><!-- some fields --></form>

<script>
    // When the form is submitted
    $("input[name='submit']").click(function(e){
        //prevent it from being sent immediatly
        e.preventDefault();
        // Send one version through Ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: "page2.cgi",
            data: $('#formID').serialize(),
            success: function(){
                // When it's done, submit the form to the "action" attribute
                $('#formID').submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```